# How to install Brave Web Browser for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: webbrowser-app

I want to install Brave Web Browser . I went to the website's download section but it has a method which is less user friendly , difficult to understand . I want to know a Simple easy way to install Brave Web Browser on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install brave` ?

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar  I have searched the packages available through apt , but it is not available there . check this screen-shot [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WMCYeDXBWloa0L-QtEoYgvB2JX6ykSHZ)

Comment: `wget -qO - https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/brave-apt/keys.asc | sudo apt-key add -
 && sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/brave-apt xenial main"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by [Brave installation manual](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/blob/master/docs/linuxInstall.md), the easiest way to install Brave web browser is as `snap` package.

Since `snap` tool is pre-installed on Ubuntu 16.04, you just need to open your terminal and run the following command:

```
snap install brave
```

Comment: After the completing the process you mentioned , I had to reboot the Computer in order to see Brave web browser in the Ubuntu Dash